# IC legs (VCCIO1) Broken Accidentlly of Xilinx XC2c128 CPLD is it working?

Tags: fpga, integrated-circuit, xilinx, programmable-logic

[image] This is the image of  My Xilinx Ic that leg name **VCCIO1** that broken yesterday ......but I found in its datasheet that their is a same **pin named VCCIO1**  are present at that time I was happy but when I try to check Continuity test on it using Multimeter,then Multimeter not show any Beep when I try to connect both 73 No VCCIO1 to 55 no VCCIO1 PIN ......I suggest both are same but multimeter not is it true ? ........please help Friends....

Comment: You need to power all the pins.

Comment: It's better to contact the manufacturer...

Answer (score 3):

Note:  there maybe exceptions so it would best to test first but the general rule is that nodes/pin that have the same names (especially power rails) are connected internally.  You can verify this by testing with an Ohm meter.  While the pin is broken off the lead frame and wire bond to the die is probably intact.

Is it recommended?  The designer doubled or tripled or etc. etc. that supply line because a single wire bond may not handle the level of current needed, or there is need to ensure low inductance or the signal routing on the chip is marginal so it was easier to route the signal externally.  So it was done for a reason.  It may well be over designed.

We can't know any of these things but you can test it and if it runs then it should be OK to play with.  Just be aware there may (or may not) be issues with performance.  I wouldn't ship it to a customer, but if its for experimenting and you don't want to spend more money it's worth a try.

EDIT after addition of picture in OP:
There is a chance that the pin damage also damaged the lead frame and you may not be able to connect to the remaining bit in the package. I would suggest to also test pin #93 as another likely candidate.  But the fact that it doesn't "beep" may not mean anything, or it may mean everything.  It's best to test it out and try.

Other than saying "it's possible that it's still working" there isn't too much that can be said or done remotely.

Comment: Why not pin 27?

Comment: @jippie why not? indeed!